# Why is the numbering of the layers reversed when building a CNN model with keras and how can I restore the correct numbering?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

When I build a CNN model, the order of the layers is correct but the numbering of the layers is reversed : the numbering is decreasing - when it should be increasing - when reading the model from top to bottom. It is probable that I made a bad manipulation because before the numbering was correct.

I thank you in advance to help me to restore the numbering in the right way!

To illustrate the problem, please find below a small reprex :

```r
library(keras)

model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 32, kernel_size = c(3,3), activation = "relu",
                input_shape = c(150, 150, 3)) %>% 
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>% 
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 64, kernel_size = c(3, 3), activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>% 
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 128, kernel_size = c(3, 3), activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 128, kernel_size = c(3, 3), activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>%
  layer_flatten() %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 512, activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")

model
#> Model
#> Model: "sequential"
#> ________________________________________________________________________________
#> Layer (type)                        Output Shape                    Param #     
#> ================================================================================
#> conv2d_3 (Conv2D)                   (None, 148, 148, 32)            896         
#> ________________________________________________________________________________
#> max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 74, 74, 32)              0           
#> ________________________________________________________________________________
#> conv2d_2 (Conv2D)                   (None, 72, 72, 64)              18496       
#> ________________________________________________________________________________
#> max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 36, 36, 64)              0           
#> ________________________________________________________________________________
#> conv2d_1 (Conv2D)                   (None, 34, 34, 128)             73856       
#> ________________________________________________________________________________
#> max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 17, 17, 128)             0           
#> ________________________________________________________________________________
#> conv2d (Conv2D)                     (None, 15, 15, 128)             147584      
#> ________________________________________________________________________________
#> max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 7, 7, 128)               0           
#> ________________________________________________________________________________
#> flatten (Flatten)                   (None, 6272)                    0           
#> ________________________________________________________________________________
#> dense_1 (Dense)                     (None, 512)                     3211776     
#> ________________________________________________________________________________
#> dense (Dense)                       (None, 1)                       513         
#> ================================================================================
#> Total params: 3,453,121
#> Trainable params: 3,453,121
#> Non-trainable params: 0
#> ________________________________________________________________________________
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: what do you mean by numbering?

Comment: What do you mean decreasing, are your referring to your convolutional layer?

Comment: What I mean by numbering is that layers #3 which are entitled "conv2d_3" and max_pooling2d3" are before the layers #2 which are entitled "conv2d_2" and max_pooling2d2" and so on when reading the model from top to bottom. This is not logical. I must have done something wrong and I would like to restore the logical order - i.e. layers #1 before layers #2, and so on.

Comment: Same comment as above for what I mean by "decreasing" - i.e. conv2d_3 is before conv2d2 which is before conv2d_1 when reading the model from top to bottom (idem for max_pooling and dense layers)